# Xamarin Forms Expander with CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Expander must contain CollectionView with Observablecollection in Observablecollection. How to link data?
This is my template for List1 =  Observablecollection(Object1):

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding List2}">
                                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                        <Grid Padding="10">
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yy}'}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </CollectionView>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Expander.ContentTemplate>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
```

This class of object:

```
public class Object1
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Object2> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create an ObservableCollection of object1

```
 public ObservableCollection<Object1> FirstList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Object1>()
        {
            new Object1(){ Name="TEST 1" ,
                Description = new ObservableCollection<Object2>(){ new Object2() { Name = "2" },
                                                               new Object2(){ Name = "3" }, new Object2(){ Name = "4" } } }
        };
```

then in your xaml binding bind this way .

```
  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FirstList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <extensions:Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <extensions:Expander.Header>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </extensions:Expander.Header>

                        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Description}">
                                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Grid Padding="10">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CollectionView>
                          
                    </extensions:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you trying to put collection view in the expander content?\

Comment: Yes, I want to put  collection view to expander

Comment: did it work? if not please inform me to fix the answer

Comment: This is a logical and good idea, but for some reason it does not work yet

Comment: Can you please specify what is not working? Like is the Name of object1 being displayed and the object 2 properties are not? or what?

Comment: Object1 name is displayed, object2 name is not displayed

Comment: It's not some UI issue

Comment: It's not working too :( I have a strange binding data for this xaml

Comment: check now please, try chaning  AncestorLevel between 1 and 3

Comment: remove this from the expander  <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

Comment: It didn't help. Thank you friend. Maybe I need to come up with another way to display the data

Comment: I tested my code and its working try to copy past it and try

Comment: However, your code and mine work on a simple example. I will look further for the problem